# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable in python for a dict

Tags: python

I have been struggling from the past 2 days basically i want to get the MeetingName for each item where the Close tag has '-1' value. The error happens on the line `if str(-1) in contents['Close']:` , sometimes it works and sometimes it gives error

```
 def meetingHandler(message):
    # path = str(message['path']).replace('/', '')
    data = message['data']
    #ended_meetings = []
    if data is not None:
        for name, contents in data.items():
            if str(-1) in contents['Close']:
                #ended_meetings.append(str(name))
                p1 = str(contents['Port_1'])
                p2 = str(contents['Port_2'])
                VoIP.close_ports(str(p1), str(p2))
                results = Constants.db.child('OnGoingMeetings').child(str(name)).remove()
            else:
                pass
```

Here is the input data in dicts.

```
<class 'dict'>: {'path': '/', 'data': {'Meeting_15911478': {'Close': -1, 'Port_1': '1245', 'Port_2': '2810'}, 'Meeting_15919478': {'Close': 0, 'Port_1': '1925', 'Port_2': '2310'}}, 'event': 'put'}
```

I have tried try except clause but still the same issue is there.
Can some one help?

Comment: `type(data)` will never be `None`, because the literal `None` only refers to a value of the type, not the type itself. You probably just want `if data is not None`, though you should probably be more specific, as an `int` is also not `None`, but `(3).items()` would fail just the same. That is, you don't care what the type of `data` is, as long as it supports the mapping protocol.

Comment: I have tried all solutions mentioned here by both of you guys but still the output is mere the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `contents['Close']` in your case is a (scalar) -1 (respective 0). No set, no list, no tuple which contains that value as a member, so it is clear that the `in` operation will fail.

You probably meant to say `contents['Close'] == -1`, as it is not a string as well an converting the `-1` to a `str` doesn't make sense as well.

---

If I take your input data and your function, modify it by

- adding my suggestion from above (`contents['Close'] == -1` instead of `str(-1) in contents['Close']`)
- replacing the VOIP and database instructions with appropriate `print()` calls

I have

```
def meetingHandler(message):
    # path = str(message['path']).replace('/', '')
    data = message['data']
    #ended_meetings = []
    if data is not None:
        for name, contents in data.items():
            #if str(-1) in contents['Close']:
            if contents['Close'] == -1:
                #ended_meetings.append(str(name))
                p1 = str(contents['Port_1'])
                p2 = str(contents['Port_2'])
                print('VoIP.close_ports(' + str(p1) + ", " + str(p2) + ")")
                print("remove", name)
            else:
                pass

message = {'path': '/', 'data': {'Meeting_15911478': {'Close': -1, 'Port_1': '1245', 'Port_2': '2810'}, 'Meeting_15919478': {'Close': 0, 'Port_1': '1925', 'Port_2': '2310'}}, 'event': 'put'}
meetingHandler(message)
```

which gives me the output

```
VoIP.close_ports(1245, 2810)
remove Meeting_15911478
```

Comment: But still even after contents['Close'] == -1 it has the same Exception.

Comment: But even if i dont wrap contents['Close'] to str it gives Exception as well saying can't iterate on a str literal.

Comment: `contents['Close'] == -1` will not produce the same exception, because there is no `str` literal involved, nor is there any iteration involved.

Comment: I wish you were saying is true but in my case its not the case.

Comment: @SaifAli did you try restarting the debugging process? Sometimes IDEs do not handle edits made while running well.

Comment: @SaifAli There it says `'int' object is not subscriptable`. That's a different message from those you described.

Comment: I have tried solutions for that aswell tried different ways but still it says int *'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @SaifAli I don't know where your problem is. I have taken your data and your code, modified it as suggested and it works. See my edited answer.